# JSON to CSV performance efficient

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv

There are couple of ways to convert JSON file to CSV, as mentioned in https://earthly.dev/blog/convert-to-from-json/

If anyone has any experience of what's going to be best in terms of performance?

(JSON object is nested, complex and ~900KB size.)

Comment: Run performance tests and find out.

Comment: I would say your biggest challenge won't be the size, and unless you have hundred thousand of these files, performance should be next to identical. Much bigger a challenge would most likely be the structure conversion. CSV is a fragile format, open to many interpretations. It's best suited for 2-dimensional data, like the article linked. You state your data is nested and complex. Post minimal examples ?